# Angular <input> changing [value] does not update it only for the first time

Tags: angular, typescript

**So I have this code in my angular project :**

```
   <div class="group-list-box row-span-5 col-span-5  rounded-lg border-2 p-5">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <p>TEMPLATE EDIT</p>
      <div *ngIf="selectedList === undefined" class="bg-green">Plz select a template first</div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedList !== undefined">
        <div class="m-5">
          <label>
            <input type="text" [value]="selectedList.templateMesage" formControlName="firstCtrl">
            <span>{{selectedList.templateMesage}}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="m-5">
          <label>
            <input type="text" [value]="selectedList.templateCaption!== undefined ? selectedList.templateCaption : ''">
            <span>{{selectedList.templateCaption!== undefined ? selectedList.templateCaption : ''}}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="m-5">
          <label>
            <input type="url" [value]="selectedList.templateAction !== undefined ? selectedList.templateAction : ''">
            <span>{{selectedList.templateAction !== undefined ? selectedList.templateAction : ''}}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="m-5">
          <label>
            <input type="text" [value]="selectedList.templateImage !== undefined ? selectedList.templateImage : ''">
            <span>{{selectedList.templateImage !== undefined ? selectedList.templateImage : ''}}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
  
      </div>
      <div>
  
        <button (click)="checkValidity()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

But when I update the selectedList for the first time , my input does not update

First Update :
[image]

Second Update :[image]

```
 firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
 });

 selectList(list:viberTemplateDetails){
    if(this.selectedListId != list.templateId && list.templateId!=undefined){
      this.selectedListId = list.templateId;
      this.selectedList = list;
    }
    console.log(this.selectedList);
  }
```

My console.log() also shows the selectedList when I change it
[image]
[image]

Is there something that I am missing? I am new to Angular and Typescript so this is maybe normal behavior and I have to do something else

Comment: You are using the `formControlName` approach, so I assume that you have a `FormGroup` defined in your `.ts` file that has the `firstCtrl` `FormControl` listed on it. Could you please include that code in your question :) If you do not have a `FormGroup` defined, that will already be part of the problem, but there are different routes we could go down to get it working

Comment: @nate-kumar I added the part where I defined the FormGroup

Answer (score 0):

You don't reference the created FormGroup. Try referencing it like this:

```
        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <input type="text" [value]="selectedList.templateMesage"
              formControlName="firstCtrl">
            <span>{{selectedList.templateMesage}}</span>
        <form>
```

I hope it helps. :)

**Update:**

I used [value] and formControlName by accident in the same Tag:

```
        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <input type="text" formControlName="firstCtrl">
            <span>{{formGroup.controls['firstCtrl'].value}}</span>
        <form>
```

Comment: I didnt have the full code , I now posted the full code with the formGroup included

Comment: Please, don't use `[value]` and `formControlName` in the same tag. If you want to give an initial value, give it when you create the formGroup or use setValue or patchValue.